# Is the given function is Riemann integrable or not reimann integrable ??

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the  given  function is Riemann integrable or  not Riemann integrable on the interval $[0,1] $?

$$ { f }(x)=\begin{cases} \cos x \quad \text{if}\quad x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]  \\ \sin x \quad \text {if} \quad x \in (\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases} $$

My attempts: I  know  that  $f$  will  continuous  when $\cos x =\sin x$  by putting $x = \pi/4$. I'm confused that here $x = \pi/4 $  is not given. Now how  can I conclude  that  it is  Riemann integrable  or not ?

Any Hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a jump discontinuity but otherwise the fact that the function is continuous at every other point should tell you it's integrable

Comment: The function is continuous almost everywhere (you have only a point of discontinuity) so the function is riemann integrable

Comment: @Cuoredicervo..how  the  Function is  continious almost  everywhere..can elaboarate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure theory approach here is a bit of overkill I think. Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $n>2.$ Choose partitions $P_n$ of $[0,1/2-1/n]$ and $Q_n$ of $[1/2+1/n,1]$ such that

$$U(P_n,f)-L(P_n,f)<\epsilon,\,\,U(Q_n,f)-L(Q_n,f)<\epsilon.$$

Then $R_n=P_n\cup Q_n$ is a partition of $[0,1],$ and

$$\tag 1 U(R_n,f)-L(R_n,f) < \epsilon + (C_n-c_n)\frac{2}{n} + \epsilon.$$

Here $C_n,c_n$ are the $\sup, \inf$ of $f$ over $[1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n].$ The Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've learned about *Darboux theory*. Then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff there exists a partition of $[a,b]$ whose sum of oscillation $\sum_1^n \omega_j \varDelta x_j < \varepsilon$. Then for the $f$ in the post, the integrability of $f$ on $[0, 1/2]$ and $[1/2, 1]$ implies the existence of partitions $\mathcal P_1, \mathcal P_2$ of each interval where the sum $\sum_{\mathcal P_k} \omega_j \varDelta x_j < \varepsilon/2 [k = 1,2]$. Then the partition of $[0,1]$ formed by union of the partitions above, whose sum $\sum \omega_j \varDelta x_j = \sum_{\mathcal P_1} + \sum_{\mathcal P_2} < \varepsilon$.

The comments has referred to following facts:

**Definition**. $f$ is continuous **almost everywhere** on the interval $[a, b]$ if for each $\varepsilon >0$ the discontinuity of $f$ could be covered by an at most countable collection of open intervals $(I_j)_1^\infty$ with total length less than $\varepsilon$.

**Theorem**. $\fbox{Lebesgue criterion}$ $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff $f$ is bounded and $f$ is almost everywhere continuous on $[a,b ]$ [Proof omitted].

Now $f$ only has one discontinuity, which could be covered by one open interval with length $\varepsilon $ as small as possible. Hence the integrability.